# Migrating document library with out losing field value

Tags: document-library, document-migration

I have a document library that would like to move to another site, I want to ensure that when it is moved I am able to preserve the values for date modified, modified by, created and created by.

In my testing I've found that I can't move it using the site template feature because it is very large and has over 2000 documents in it. I tried doing a backup and restore but this method replaced the values which wasn't what I was looking for.

I've found that there are 3rd party tools like ShareGate and Metalogix which work but they are not able to move all of them in the trial version and cost is to much for this one need.

Is there a way I can accomplish this or are my options null at this point?

Comment: Are the libraries under the same site collection?

Comment: Yes they are...

Answer (score 0):

You can use out of the box SharePoint Content and Structure tool. For using this Publishing Infrastructure should be enabled.

1. Open the source site
2. Site actions
3. Site settings
4. Site administration
5. Content and structure
6. Select the list or document library from the left hand side- click on it.
7. Associated items will be reflected in the right hand side pane.
8. Actions
9. You will get the options as Move, copy and delete.